# Tensorflow convolutional autoencoders doesn't converge with my data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

My problem is to create an autoencoder model to recognize anomalies on a cardboard-like surface. I know that I can use an autoencoder and train it using "good" samples, and later I can use it to recognize "bad" samples (i.e., anomalies).

I've built convolutional autoencoders in Tensorflow based on [Building autoencoder in Keras](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and [PyImageSearch autoencoders](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/17/autoencoders-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/). Both examples use MNIST dataset and they work perfectly (loss is decreasing, accuracy is growing up to about 0.85). However, I tried to train both autoencoders using my custom pictures, and the problem is that my models don't converge - the training loss (I tried `binary_crossentropy` and `mse` as stated in the websites) gets stuck at some level, e.g. `3.0873e-04` or `0.0016` (depending on loss and way of normalizing the data), and accuracy is `0` or sth like `1.2618e-07`. Below is the sample network architecture.

```
input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential()
data_augmentation.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'))
data_augmentation.add(tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('vertical'))

x = data_augmentation(input_layer, 0)

x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
# the block below was added once and removed later to reduce network depth
x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = layers.Conv2D(8, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
# the block below was added once and removed later to reduce network depth - END
x = layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)
autoencoder = Model(input_layer, decoded)
```

My dataset consists of about 50k pictures of size 50x50 (and resized to 28x28) presenting tiny parts of cardboard-like sheet: [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnQzJ.jpg), [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4XNL.jpg), and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2dC1.jpg) you can see the source 900x900 picture I used to create 50x50 pictures. For the model, I convert them to grayscale.

I used two ways of data normalization: the first one (taken from the websites) was to split their values by 255, and the second one was to use min-max normalization. The pixel values are in range 59-168. Here is how I create the dataset:

```
imgs = [cv2.imread(fname) for fname in glob.glob('{}/*.jpg'.format(dir_with_pictures))]
imgs = [img for img in imgs if img is not None]  # to remove pictures which OpenCV was not able to load for some reason
dataset = np.array([np.expand_dims(np.array(cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (28, 28)), axis=-1) for img in imgs])
dataset = (dataset - np.min(dataset)) / (np.max(dataset) - np.min(dataset))  # one way of normalization, OR
dataset = dataset.astype('float32') / 255.0  # second way of normalization
```

And here I compile my model, and later it's trained using my dataset - either the whole dataset, or the training set creating by splitting the dataset 80/20:

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is it possible that items in my dataset are 'too similar' to each other and that's why I can't train a good model? Or may there be anything other wrong with the dataset? What can I try to get a converging model? Should I pay attention to accuracy metric?

Comment: There is actually nothing wrong, the loss is decreasing to a good low value, but your autoencoder does regression, and accuracy is a metric meant for classification only. The examples are actually wrong on using accuracy for that purpose, it only works because the data has lots of 0's and 1's.

Comment: Try removing activation `sigmoid` on the last layer and using `MSE` for the training. There could be many reason why the loss get "stucked" and might also come from how you processed the data...